# Unit Test build failing when importing MagicalRecord

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, magicalrecord, cocoapods

I have a project setup using the UnitTest template provided by Apple. Too I added MagicalRecord to Prefix header. When I am running on the device and Simulator everything is working fine.
Except the Unit Tests, when I am compiling for the unit tests the build failed with the following command: `'CoreData+MagicalRecord.h' file not found` . This happens in the prefix header.

prefix.pch

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the '123tv' target in the '123tv' project
//

#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 3.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Environments.h"
    #import "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h"    
    #import "PBLog.h"
#endif
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Are the `Header Search Paths` set up correctly for the test target?

Comment: nope they weren't. Is there a way to automate this? Add your comment as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the `Header Search Paths` is set up correctly for your test target.

I generally use [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) which will automate this stuff for you

Comment: I'm using cocoapods and I have this same issue.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Also using cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run command (1) in terminal, then add import in step (2)

1. In your project directory

`run pod update`

2. You should now be able to add

`#import <MagicalRecord/CoreData+MagicalRecord.h>`

to any of your target's source files and begin using MagicalRecord!