# Pod CoreData+MagicalRecord.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I recently had to delete a xcode project from my computer and re-clone it down. After cloning it, I ran a `pod install` and then went to build the project. However, I kept hitting a error in my .pch file that claimed a file (a pod file) was not found.

I looked into the following SO posts:

[iOS - Build fails with CocoaPods cannot find header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files)

[Unit Test build failing when importing MagicalRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008956/unit-test-build-failing-when-importing-magicalrecord)

From there I gathered that I needed to add to **Header Search Paths** the `$(inherited)` flag. I've done that, I've cleaned the project, and then re-built it, and still am having the following error..

[image: PCH File]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As of version `2.3.0` (released on 1 June 2015) the file `CoreData+MagicalRecord.h` seems to have been **renamed** to `MagicalRecord.h` only.

If you installed MagicalRecord using CocoaPods and ran `pod install` or `pod update` again you might have gotten this new version and will end up with the same error message: `CoreData+MagicalRecord.h file not found`

So you should change the `import` of the header in your `pch` file then. This is what I have now:

[image: MagicalRecord header file change in pch file]

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this line on top of your podfile:

```
link_with  ['ProjectName', 'ProjectNameTests']
```

before this line

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
```

Install pod, and at your project Build Setting->Other Linker Flags, add $(inherited).

Comment: As a note to anyone else, I started receiving `diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory` for my ProjectNameTests directory. So, I had to go into Project Deployment Target, click "Info", and under "Configurations" had to set ProjectNameTests to use Pods.debug configuration file

Answer (score 0):

## import "MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h"

Answer (score -1):

Try to run command (1) in terminal, then add import in step (2)

1. In your project directory,run `pod update`
2. You should now be able to add

`#import <MagicalRecord/CoreData+MagicalRecord.h>`

to any of your target's source files and begin using MagicalRecord!

I think with 2 steps you can be solved this problem.